# Error when trying to install react-devtools

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install react-devtools with this code

```
sudo npm install -g react-devtools
```

after running this command, I am getting this error.

```
/usr/local/bin/react-devtools -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-devtools/bin.js

> electron@1.6.11 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-devtools/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-devtools/node_modules/electron/install.js:47
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-devtools/node_modules/electron/.electron'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@1.6.11 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jayakrishnan/.npm/_logs/2017-08-07T11_22_05_742Z-debug.log
```

How can I correct this? I am desperately in need of devtools for debugging. If possible, please suggest better debugging tools for React Native.

Comment: try this,  sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local and rerun the install

Comment: Please explain what this does

Comment: it changes the directory /usr/local owner to your user account,

Comment: is it owned by root now?

Comment: I am getting this error: chown: missing operand after ‘jayakrishnan/usr/local’

Comment: can you go to /usr and check local folder properties->permision tab or navigate to /usr directory and type "stat local" via command line

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 18):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/741) try the following command to fix this issue:

```
sudo npm install -g react-devtools --unsafe-perm=true
```

`allow-root` option doe's not solving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by using yarn.

```
brew install yarn
yarn global add react-devtools
```

You don't need to change permissions this way.

Answer (score 1):

**use this command it will solve your error:**

sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Answer (score -1):

I have been resolved in Ubuntu 18.04 by

> sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/node_modules
>
> sudo npm install -g --verbose react-devtools@4

Comment: chmod 777 on /usr folder is unreal